# Is there an option to redirect to another page on button click in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner to react and creating a login page in which i want to redirect to another page on clicking of login button.how can we achieve this?

Comment: if you are writing an SPA you want to use react-router

Comment: As @oshell commented. Checkout this [link to react-router example.js file](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) Link are used to change the route, depending on that link, specific components are loaded.

Comment: thanks, but I want to navigate to the new page instead of loading a component on the same page.

Comment: oh then, I suppose you can go with window.location = "brandnewpage.html" on login button click. and I suppose you'd have a whole another ReactComponent/Project in that brandnewpage.html.